# Вывести с помощью Javascript значения html формы

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, у меня есть код:

```
<input type="hidden" value="'.$sql_array['id'].'" name="customer_id">
```

хотел вывести значение customer_id через джаваскрипт, как можно написать это?

Answer (score 1):

Не до конца понял вопрос. Если требуется вывести свойства поля ввода с заданным атрибутом name, тогда

```
var values = document.getElementsByName("customer_id");

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    alert(values[i].value);
    alert(values[i].name);
    alert(values[i].type);
}
```

Дополнение к комментарию. Проще всего так:

```
document.write(document.getElementsByName("customer_id")[0].value);
```

Comment: Будем считать, что есть такая строка:

    <input type="hidden" value="НАДО ВЫВЕСТИ НА ЭКРАН" name="name">

Вот, надо сделать на Javascript так, чтобы на экране было написано:

>НАДО ВЫВЕСТИ НА ЭКРАН

Comment: Обновил ответ.